# No "Hello" icon in Firefox 34

Tags: firefox, kubuntu

I've just upgraded to Firefox 34, but cannot see "Hello" icon on Firefox toolbar.

[image]

I could not find any info on that in Internet.

There is no "Hello" icon there in "Additional Tools and Features"

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to Enable/get the Hello button in Firefox 34 customize window?

1. Visit `about:config`
2. Change `loop.throttled` preference value to `false`.
3. Restart the browser, Hello button now appears when you open the Customizing mode, drag and drop it onto the menu or toolbar and start making video calls with your friends.

Comment: any reason why it isn't default? and will this change with an update?

Comment: Mozilla says "The feature is being made available to users on a gradual basis to ensure that our server infrastructure is able to keep up with the load." (see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-firefox-hello-button)